Validate fax with repeating numbers using regex
I am currently validating faxes/phones using the following regex:
^(\+?)([\(]?\d{1}[\)]?((\s{1})|(-)?))?([\(]?\d{3}[\)]?-?\s?\d{3}-?\s?\d{4}\s?)?$

Unfortunately, with this regex, the following fax number is valid: 1111111111
What should I add to the following regex to take care of the duplicates?
^(\+?)([\(]?\d{1}[\)]?((\s{1})|(-)?))?([\(]?\d{3}[\)]?-?\s?\d{3}-?\s?\d{4}\s?)?$


Just add (?![\s-]*(\d)(?:[\s-]*\1)*[\s-]*$) after ^.

I added a comment to the original answer.
